# How to scroll/hide a parent header view from a RecyclerView scroll in child FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android

Sorry, that title is a bit confusing. I've included a wireframe of my screen below.

**A** - a FrameLayout which acts as the header in the Activity and houses a Fragment

**B** - a SlidingTabLayout for the FragmentPagerAdapter in C

**C** - a FragmentPagerAdapter that houses Fragments with RecyclerViews (grids) as their layout

**What I want to accomplish:**

As the user scrolls through the grid RecyclerView in C, I want header A to scroll up and be hidden (similar to Material Design Toolbars being hidden on scroll). I also want the tabs in B to be locked on the top of the screen once A is completely hidden but I think that part would just follow easily as a consequence of accomplishing the scroll/hide on A.

Ideally, I'd like it to be a smooth scroll that matches the distance of the user's scroll. But my backup plan is to just have a slide-up animation in the A fragment that's triggered by a certain scroll magnitude in the C fragment (the trigger would be sent up through C's fragment listener interface - the parent activity).

[image]